# Accessing GCP secret key with /actuator/refresh endpoint in spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, secret-key, google-secret-manager, spring-cloud-config-server, spring-cloud-gcp

I am accessing GCP secret key in Spring boot config Server / Client with 'sm://' and it's working perfectly when application started.

Now I am invoking '/actuator/refresh' endpoint.. here application failed to bind the property specified for secret key with sm:// prefix.

However, if I provide plain text, that works fine; so issue is accessing secret key from Google cloud.

Can anyone help me on the same !

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, it is not possible to refresh or load secrets using the `actuator/refresh` endpoint due to limitations with Spring (specifically the mechanism called "bootstrap loading" which is how the secrets are loaded by the `.properties` files.).

Details are provided here: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-gcp/issues/2485